# If $V=V_1\oplus V_2 = V_3 \oplus V_4$, then are $V_1$ and $V_3$ isomorphic? Same question with $V_2$ and $ V_4$

Tags: linear-algebra, quotient-spaces, direct-sum, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $V$ be a vector space on a field or characteristic $0$. Also, let $V_1, V_2, V_3$ and $V_4$ be subspaces of $V$ such that $$V=V_1\oplus V_2 = V_3 \oplus V_4.$$

Obviously, if $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are dubspaces of $V$ such that $X \oplus Y = X \oplus Z$ since $X \cong V/Y$ and $Y \cong V/X$ and so $$Y \cong V/X \cong Z.$$

**My question is: Can this be generalized a little bit. I.e. if $V=V_1\oplus V_2 = V_3 \oplus V_4$ the $V_1 \cong V_3$ and $V_2 \cong V_4$? Or do I need some conditions about those four subspaces.**

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $V_1 = V_2 = \mathbb{R}^2,\ V_3 = \mathbb{R},$ and $V_4 = \mathbb{R}^3.$

Comment: You’re right! Thanks! I can’t think of conditions to add to the subspaces so that the affirmation is valid. Is there such conditions?

Comment: The only meaningful condition I can think of is the one you already described, where $V_1$ is isomorphic to $V_3.$ Note that vector spaces over $k$ are completely determined by their dimension, so if the dimension of $V_i$ is $d_i,$ then what you're asking becomes "if $d_1 + d_2 = d_3 + d_4,$ is $d_1 = d_3$?"

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much!